# Programatically Adding Product to Magento Cart 1.8

Tags: php, magento, cart

I have tried a lot of different suggestions to get this to work, none of which have - these include the `addToCart` URL method and the `$cart->addProduct` method.

I can not seem to find any other way of doing this, and have also not found anyone on 1.8 to have this working.

What I am doing is adding a sample system to the site, this means that a product is added to the system programatically (Which works great) and then add this product to the cart (uh oh).

Comment: Seem to be an issue in 1.8, for a workaround take a look @

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter

Comment: The work around doesn't seem to work for me...