# How to add product to cart programmatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento, session

I am unable to add product to cart programmatically in Magento , I have tried every possible technique to add product with quantity to cart ( in Magento), following are the things I have tried and forums/sites taken help from. But none of them is working. I am using Magento Community edition 1.9.1.1. If anyone has any suggestion/answer, please share.

- Tried to do it via URL - e.g. `[Magento_Store_URL]/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]` or even like this -  `[Magento_Store_URL]/checkout/cart/add/product/[id]/qty/[qty]`. I have also tried with `form_key`, generated via `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();`. All these stuff is not working at all. These things are mentioned here - [Magento website](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)
- Next, I have tried via programmatically, like this.

```html
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app(); 
$product=new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(1); // 1 is product id, this is simple product ( type)
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->addProduct($product, 1 ); // quantity is 1
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init(); // tried commenting this too!
$cart->addProduct($product, 1 ); // quantity is 1
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$quote->collectTotals()->save(); header('Location: '. 'http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart');
```

- Also tried following.

```html
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$params=array( 'product'=>1, 'qty' => 3 );
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load($params["product"]);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
header('Location: '. 'http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart');
```

I have taken help from following websites.

- http://gzchauhan.blogspot.in/2012/03/programmatically-add-product-in-cart-in.html
- [Magento - Add a product to the cart via query string without form_key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter/19999360#19999360)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17997/product-not-adding-to-cart
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32967/programmatically-adding-product-to-cart-returns-empty-price
- http://subasd.com.np/magento-programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-custom-options/

Is there any wrong in my code, whatever I have tried or is there any setting issue with my Magento Installation?

**Update 1**
I have tried below from the answer [proposed to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30821628/932584), still that is **not** working.

```html
$formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
$params = array(
    'product' => 3,
    'qty' => 2,
 'form_key' => $formKey
);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($params['product']);
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

**Update 2**

This is working, if I create a controller and place all code there, not working - in a standalone page that refers /app/Mage.php .

Comment: Not sure but maybe you have to indicate in your script the current store before save: Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: I have only one store, have tried your suggestion, still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1.8 you won't be able to add a product to the cart from a GET request alone, as you need to provide the form_key.

You should be able to add a product to the cart using the following:

`form_key` is the main thing to get right here.

```
$params //should include at least a valid form_key, qty

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(
                        Mage::app()
                        ->getStore()
                        ->getId()
                    )
                    ->load($product_id);

$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

Take a look at the `addProduct` function in app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php if you need to debug (and then in the app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php too)

Comment: Thanks for info, I will check that and will get back to you.

Comment: Update: This is working, if I create a controller and place all code there, not working - in a standalone page that refers /app/Mage.php

Comment: Can you post the whole standalone script? (I would guess this is due to the session being booted, and it doesn't match the session you're then loading in a browser?)

Comment: This is mentioned in other question I posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725878/rebuild-checkout-page-in-magento-ce-on-passing-quote-id-as-querystring , check the last part ( 2 lines). I used those 2 line at top of php script, followed by your code, last line is to redirect to checkout/cart link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easy way to add product to cart/quote:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
// load quote by customer and store...
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$quote->setIsActive(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```