# Magento 1.9.X add product with custom options to cart from external site

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, cart

I have an external website which allows a customer to design a product, then uses an HTML form to post this data.  I need to take this information and add this product (with custom options) to the customer's cart in our Magento website, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I tried something simple at first using URL redirect, but Magento 1.9.X no longer supports adding to cart like this:

```
$cart_url = "website.com/checkout/cart/add/product=" . $product_id . "&qty=1" //Include custom options somehow

<form action=<?php echo $cart_url?>>
     <input type="hidden" value="pid"> product id </input>
     <input type="hidden" value="option1"> custom option 1</input>
</form>
```

Doing research shows that I can also add an item with custom options through either writing a custom Controller or Events/Observers to add the item, but as I'm new to Magento I'm not sure how to trigger events and observer functions from outside of Magento.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom module in magento.

Create a file app/etc/MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
            </depends>
        </MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create a file app/code/local/MyExtension/AddProductFromUrl/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl before="Mage_Checkout">MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl</MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create a file app/code/local/MyExtension/AddProductFromUrl/controllers/CartController.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
    class MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
        # overloaded addAction
        public function addAction() {        
            // generate form_key if missing or invalid
            if (!($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null)) || $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()) {
                $this->getRequest()->setParams(array('form_key' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
            }        

            // do parent actions
            parent::addAction();
        }
    }
?>
```

Also see

- [Magento - Add a product to the cart via query string without form_key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/i-want-to-use-add-to-cart-via-url-in-magento-1-8-but-dont-know-which-files-to-c

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Using this, how do I use this in my external website?  As in, what URL do I pass to my HTML form to call the controller?  One of the links tells the user to point to `root/cart/index/index/product/ID_HERE`.  How does that change for your case?  How do I add custom options to the product this way?  Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE I've gotten it working!  Overriding addAction was having issues as I need both a custom functionality and the normal functionality for the magento store and our custom store, so I've created a new Action and it all works correctly!

Comment: Sorry aaron! just saw your messages, Congrats :D

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a bit in 1.9.0.1, but St0iK's solution above worked with the following changes:

> 1) place the module .xml file in app/etc/modules (as opposed to app/etc)
>
> 2) In the controller file - i had to remove `_Checkout_`

```
 class MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
```

to

```
 class MyExtension_AddProductFromUrl_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
```

After these minor edits, it works perfectly.  Not sure if these were only necessary for 1.9.0.1, but for whatever reason, they were.

To add a product to the cart, i just use the URL format

```
YOURSTORE.com/checkout/cart/add/product/123/qty/1
```

Great solution for external `PPC` or `SEO` landing pages that need a simple "buy now" button that drops right into your magento cart.